# git lfs "Could not check out <file>"

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm trying to clone a repository which uses `git-lfs`.
Although main clone went fine, when I try to run `git lfs pull` some of the files are not updated and it prints error of form:

```
Could not checkout out "path/to/file"
```

What could be the problem?

All of the files which are not downloaded have been locked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that since files were `lockable` `git-lfs` couldn't change them since they are cloned as locked.

To fix just unlock them (add user write permission).